# Unable to update value from a textbox to database

Tags: php

I'm unable to update my new price into the database. The database won't update. I am not sure where my code went wrong.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Menu_id']. " </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Menu_type']. " </td>";
  echo "<td>" ."<input type =text name=Price value =" .$row['Price']. " </td>";                           
  echo "<td>" ."<input type=submit name=Update value=Update"." </td>";
  echo "<td>" ."<input type =hidden name=hidden value = " .$row['Menu_id']. " </td>";

  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

}


if(isset($_POST['Update'])){

  $sqlAdd = "UPDATE Menu SET Price ='$_POST[Price]' WHERE Menu_id ='$_POST[hidden]'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sqlAdd );

  if(mysqli_query($con, $sqlAdd)){
    echo '<p><strong><font color = "red">The price for Menu id '.$Menu_id.' is updated.</strong></font>';
    //redirect page
    header('Refresh :5 ; url = UpdateMenuPrice.php');

  } 
  else {
    echo "failed <br>";
  }
```

The price is not updated.

Comment: is this really the minimum code example? sounds to me like you could limit it to the two lines doing the SQL query (if you are sure that these two lines get executed, which you can check by adding some output statement in front and after them)

Comment: Some general notes here: `$_POST[Price]` _probably_ should be `$_POST['Price']` or even `$_POST['price']`, unless you have defined a constant `Post`, same for `$_POST[hidden]`... Then, you definitely should start reading about the danger of "sql injection" and how to use "prepared statements" to prevent that danger you face with that code.

Answer (score 0):

You forget the closing brackets as well as your query is not formatted properly.

```
 echo "<td>" ."<input type =text name=Price value =" .$row['Price']. "></td>";                           
                    echo "<td>" ."<input type=submit name=Update value=Update >"." </td>";
                    echo "<td>" ."<input type =hidden name=hidden value = " .$row['Menu_id']. "> </td>";
```

You must have use single quote when working with $_REQUEST, $_POST, $_GET.
Here is your query.

```
$sqlAdd = "UPDATE Menu SET Price ='".$_POST['Price']."' WHERE Menu_id ='".$_POST['hidden']."'";
```

Comment: I feel I cant get the value of the inbox of the price. Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: which method you are using in the form means **post** or **get**. I think it might be problem here.  And what is in the **$Menu_id**, i mean have you assigned any value to **$Menu_id**  or not???

Comment: I using  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">

Comment: it keep grabbing the value of the last id of hidden

Comment: hi which one do you mean

Comment: $Menu_id  is getting the input from the database

Comment: have you checked your database??. If not then check it first and replace your query with my query. Because you haven't formatted it properly. There is no problem with your code . And show me the code in which **$Menu_id** is getting the input from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the angle bracket on each of your input elements.

You also should have quotes around your HTML form values. You can use double quotes escaped with a backslash, single quotes, or make use of HEREDOC syntax as here:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo <<<HTML
    <tr>
        <td>{$row['Menu_id']}</td>
        <td>{$row['Menu_type']}</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Price" value="{$row['Price']}"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="Update" value="Update"></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="{$row['Menu_id']}"></td>
    </tr>
HTML;
}

echo "</table>";
```

Your $_POST variables in the update section should not be enclosed in quotes, but should have single quotes in the square brackets (the same way the $row array shows above).

Lastly, with your code it is very easy for someone to hack your database to read all of your database data, delete it, or change it. You need to prevent SQL injection by using prepared statements.

Comment: If I close every column will have something like menu >